# How to trace an error most likely due to server call?

Tags: r

If you have installed OSRM API version 5 in `C:/OSRM_API5/` the following loop in the reproducible example below generates an error (more or less at a randrom time. Last time I ran the code it was when `i=17`. We ran the code on 3 different laptops and obtain the following different messages:

> Error in viaroute5(locs$x[i], locs$y[i], locs$x[j], locs$y[j]) :
>   object 'res' not found In addition: Warning messages:   1: In
>   file(con, "r") :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Die Serververbindung
>   konnte nicht hergestellt werden.' 2: In value[3L] : reached
>   elapsed time limit [cpu=1s, elapsed=1s]

or

> Error in options() : reached elapsed time limit In addition: Warning
>   message:   In file(con, "r") :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Die
>   Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden.'

or

> Error in paste("Error in", dcall, ": ") : reached elapsed time limit

Initially we thought, the `setWinProgressBar`, but now the error remains although `setWinProgressBar` is commented out.

Does anybody have an idea what happens or how to trace this error?

```
viaroute5 <- function(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, instructions) {
  address <- "http://localhost:5000"
  request <- paste(address, "/route/v1/driving/",
                     lng1, ",", lat1, ";", lng2, ",", lat2,
                     "?overview=false", sep = "", NULL)

  R.utils::withTimeout({
    repeat {
      res <- try(
        route <- rjson::fromJSON(
          file = request))
      if (class(res) != "try-error") {
        if (!is.null(res)) {
          break
        } else {
          stop("???")
        }
      }
    }
  }, timeout = 1, onTimeout = "warning")

  if (res$code == "Ok") {
      return(res$routes[[1]]$duration)
    } else {
      t_guess <- 16*60
      warning("Route not found: ", paste(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, collapse = ", "),
              ". Time set to ", t_guess/60 , " min.")
  }
}


n <- 1e3 # ................................... if set to 10, everything is fine!
locs <- data.frame(x = c(47.424536, 47.427061),
                   y = c(9.365103, 9.365062), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# pb <- winProgressBar(title = "Test",
#                      label = "0% done", min=0, max=100, initial=0)
wd <- getwd()
setwd("C:/OSRM_API5")
shell(paste0("osrm-routed ", "switzerland-latest.osrm", " >nul 2>nul"), wait = F)
Sys.sleep(3) # OSRM needs time
setwd(wd)
for (i in 1:n) {
  print(i)
  # info <- paste0("done ", round(i/nrow(locs)*100, 1), "%")
  # setWinProgressBar(pb, i/nrow(locs)*100, label = info)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    viaroute5(locs$x[1], locs$y[1], locs$x[2], locs$y[2])
  }
}
shell("TaskKill /F /IM osrm-routed.exe >nul 2>nul")
# close(pb)
```

**Comment 1**
If I replace `viaroute5(locs$x[1], locs$y[1], locs$x[2], locs$y[2])` by something trivial, e.g. `i+j` the error is gone (of course).

**Comment 2**
When I started from `i=17 it looked like

```
[1] 17
Error in file(con, "r") : reached elapsed time limit
Error in file(con, "r") : reached elapsed time limit
[1] 18
[1] 19
[1] 20
[1] 21
[1] 22
[1] 23
[1] 24
Error in readLines(file, warn = FALSE) : reached elapsed time limit
[1] 25
[1] 26
[1] 27
[1] 28
[1] 29
[1] 30
[1] 31
[1] 32
[1] 33
[1] 34
Error in viaroute5(locs$x[1], locs$y[1], locs$x[2], locs$y[2]) : 
  object 'res' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file(con, "r") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'Die Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden.'
2: In value[[3L]](cond) : reached elapsed time limit [cpu=1s, elapsed=1s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to requests coming faster than OSRM can handle them. This leads to a full OSRM request-queue and at last to spooky error messages. See [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/1771) for a partial explanation.

Using the latest `OSRMR` release from github you should not get this kind of error anymore. In `v0.1.31` I changed the `viaroute` function of `OSRMR` package to account for this by adding a new optional parameter `timeout`. `timeout` puts the `viaroute` call to sleep for 1 ms by default. The `timeout` can also be adjusted.

You can install the latest `OSRMR` release from github with:

```
devtools::install_github("ims-fhs/osrmr")
```

The following reproducible example works for me:

```
osrmr::run_server("switzerland-latest", "C:/OSRM_API5")

n <- 1e3
locs <- data.frame(x = c(47.424536, 47.427061),
                   y = c(9.365103, 9.365062), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:n) {
  print(i)
  for (j in 1:n) {
    osrmr::viaroute(locs$x[1], locs$y[1], locs$x[2], locs$y[2], instructions = FALSE, api_version = 5, localhost = TRUE, timeout = 0.001)
  }
}
osrmr::quit_server()
```